# Why PostgreSQL is not parsing large XML data?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I want to check the capability of XML in PostgreSQL before moving large data into the Database.

I have a simple test to check the XML Capability in PostgreSQL. It works with 3000000 XML formed data but not with 4000000.

✅ 
`select xml_is_well_formed('<test>' || repeat('월', 3000000) || '</test>');`

❌
`select xml_is_well_formed('<test>' || repeat('월', 4000000) || '</test>');`

This is what my XML Capability test looks like:
XML_Test.sh

```
#### XML capabilities
sql1="select xml_is_well_formed('<test>' || repeat('월', 3000000) || '</test>');"
sql2="select xml_is_well_formed('<test>' || repeat('월', 4000000) || '</test>');"

status="OK:"

ret=$(echo "$sql1" | psql -At -U $user -h $host $db)

if [ "$ret" != "t" ]
then
  status="FAILED:"
fi
echo "  $status XML capability (test 1/libxml): "

status="OK:"

ret=$(echo "$sql2" | psql -At -U $user -h $host $db)

if [ "$ret" != "t" ]
then
  status="FAILED:"
fi
echo "  $status XML capability (test 2/libxml): "
```

I'm using Amazon Linux AMI and my PostgreSQL version is: 9.2.24 and using the default PostgreSQL configuration.

**Edit:**
My total system memory is 32 GB.

Running the below command is only indicating whether the test is passing or not:

```
$ echo "select xml_is_well_formed('<test>' || repeat('월', 4000000) || '</test>')" | psql -At -U USER -h localhost DB
f


$ echo "select xml_is_well_formed('<test>' || repeat('월', 3000000) || '</test>')" | psql -At -U USER -h localhost DB
t
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't tell us the error message, nobody can help you. Please [edit] the question for that.

Comment: The answer to the "why" question in your title is probably "because you need more memory". I'm a little surprised that you didn't tell us the size of the XML being parsed and the amount of memory available.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbeI've updated the question. The statement only tells (True and False) based on the condition. What could be the other possible way to get the exact error?

Comment: @Muhaddis the only thing this shows is that the test is invalid. There's only 1 XML element with a huge amount of text that can't be queried - there's no structure there. The method `xml_is_well_formed` isn't used in querying and doesn't have to work with such amounts anyway. It's the *loader's* job to ensure the input is valid - and a single XML element with 1GB of text isn't a valid choice. It's a BLOB and should be treated as one. The query doesn't test loading, insertion, indexing or querying.

Comment: @Muhaddis the only way this input can be used is as raw text for a full-text search query. It's not even big data, it's just a *single* BLOB.

Comment: @Muhaddis in all XML systems and libraries, large amounts of data are handled using SAX interfaces. When you have 100MB of data to insert, it makes no sense to wait for all 100MB to be read into memory before you start processing them. SAX and SAX-like interfaces read and parse elements as they appear in the input stream, which means that by the time they finish reading the input, the output may already be available.

Comment: @Muhaddis *Databases*, even document databases, shred XML docs into individual elements and index those, allowing them to quickly query them. That's what makes this test unsuitable - there's only 1 element with an opaque value. There's nothing to query or indexe there

Comment: "version is: 9.2.24"  This is ancient and unsupported.  There have been a lot of improvement since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a restriction on the underlying xml parser library.

```
=> SELECT xmlparse(document '<?xml version="1.0"?><test>' || repeat('월', 4000000) || '</test>');
ERROR:  invalid XML document
DETAIL:  line 1: xmlSAX2Characters: huge text node
��월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월
                                                                               ^
line 1: Extra content at the end of the document
��월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월월
                                                                               ^
```

Perhaps a 1GB limit on text nodes or some such.

To be honest, if you are planning to work with multi-GB xml documents I suspect you want a special-purpose system rather than a general RDBMS.

Comment: Databases can handle much bigger BLOBs just fine. The OP tried to *validate* this single-element, 3M character XML file *in memory*. All document, graph or relational databases would choke on that. *None* of them needs to do something like that - their XML contents are already parsed, shredded and valid. It's the loader that needs to validate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for clarification. I think parsing is not the word to use here.

Comment: @Muhaddis you should explain what you want to do, what the real problem is, in the question itself then. What you tried doesn't demonstrate anything. I suspect the method can handle far bigger XML strings if it doesn't have to cache individual multi-MB tokens in memory.